# Bash command for drawing mapping in Elastic Search

Tags: bash, shell, elasticsearch

I have following command for drawing mapping for Elastic Search:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -XPOST $1:9200/$2/$3/_mapping -d '{
    $3: {
                "properties": {
                   "geometry": {
                      "properties": {
                         "coordinates": {
                            "type": "double"
                         },
                         "type": {
                            "type": "string"
                         }
                      }
                   },
                   "type": {
                      "type": "string"
                   },
                   "properties": {
                      "properties": {
                         "Description": {
                            "type": "string"
                         },
                         "Name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index":"not_analyzed"
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
    }
}'
```

But **'$3: {'** at the third line, its giving $3 instead of user input.

Now how can i give the value dynamically at that point.

Comment: you need to use double quotes to have parameters expanded.

Comment: You mean "$3"? If so, still it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

In single quote bash expands noting indeed. Close the single quote, use $3 and reopen single quote.

```
   curl -XPOST $1:9200/$2/$3/_mapping -d '{
       "'$3'": {
            "properties": {
               "geometry": {
```